# How do I get data from multiple excel files and use them to create a new sheet

Tags: python, excel

I have two sheets.
Sheet 1 has a comprehensive list of id numbers and their categories.
Sheet 2 has a shorter list of id numbers and associated values.

Goals:
1. look at each id and value in sheet 1
2. use that information to get the category of each value from sheet 2
3. sort the values by category into different columns in a new sheet

I'm trying to teach myself how to automate checking excel files, but I'm having a hard time. I've tried using openpyxl and xlrd. I don't know which is better for this situation.

My last attempt was using xlrd. I tried to use a for loop to get the contents of each row in the form of a list. I got stuck trying to iterate over every row except the first one.

```
import xlrd

#Opening workbook
wb1 = xlrd.open_workbook('DummySheet1.xlsx') #id and values
wb2 = xlrd.open_workbook('DummySheet2.xlsx') #id and category

#Opening specific sheets
wb1sheet1 = wb1.sheet_by_index(0)
print wb1sheet1.name
wb2sheet1 = wb2.sheet_by_index(0)
print wb2sheet1.name

#function for checking cells
def check():
    for i in range(wb1sheet1.nrows):
        list= wb1sheet1.row_values(i) 
        print(list)


check()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Read the sheet using the following code, for more refer [HERE](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
import pandas as pd

wb1 = pd.read_excel('DummySheet1.xlsx')
wb2 = pd.read_excel('DummySheet2.xlsx')
```

2.Merge the data using the merge command, refer [HERE](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging):

```
result = pd.merge(wb1, wb2, on=id)
```

3.Sort the values using the following code, refer [HERE](https://thispointer.com/pandas-sort-rows-or-columns-in-dataframe-based-on-values-using-dataframe-sort_values/):

```
result = result.sort_values(by ='category' )
```

4.Write the data to a new sheet, refer [HERE](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
result.to_excel(newFileName)
```

Check if this works for you.